# ASP.NET Identity: Manually decode Facebook tokens

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-mvc-5, identity, asp.net-identity-2

I'm in the process of converting a website from using a third-party identity provider to use ASP.NET Identity 2 instead. **The site currently does not use any OWIN middleware** but simply passes user-provided credentials to the identity provider. We then create a session token if the credentials are correct, and we use the session token on subsequent requests to reconstruct the user's session.

My goal is to get away from using the third-party provider with the minimum of code changes, so my idea is to use the `UserManager` class in ASP.NET Identity as a drop-in replacement for our third-party provider. In other words, we wouldn't use any `Startup.Auth.cs` magic to configure automatic challenge-response or cookie setting/validation middleware. We would simply take the user-provided credentials, test them using `UserManager.FindAsync`, and then continue using our existing flow.

My problem comes with dealing with Facebook logins. Currently, we show a login dialog that, upon successful login, sends us a Facebook token. We then send this token to the third-party provider, who validates it and magically turns it into an email address, first name, and last name. I can't figure out how to do this myself.

I see that if I use the out-of-the-box sample application for ASP.NET Identity, it will do the same thing via OWIN middleware. **What I don't see is any way for me to take the token and use some classes somewhere in ASP.NET Identity to convert the token into usable data myself, manually.**

(Note: I do see that I can use the Facebook Graph API along with my app ID, app secret, and user token, to recover the name of the user, but I don't get the email address, so something about this approach must be different from what the OWIN middleware is doing.)

Therefore, my questions are:

- How do I do manually validate and decode the Facebook token in the same way that ASP.NET Identity OWIN middleware is doing it?
- Is this a really dumb idea?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: _"We then send this token to the third-party provider, who validates it and magically turns it into an email address, first name, and last name. I can't figure out how to do this myself."_ - it’s called _making an API request_, which is essentially what those tokens are for in the first place.

Comment: CBroe, thanks. My understanding was that the token itself contained some data and a signature. Maybe I'm conflating that with something else. So you're saying that you think the identity provider is simply making a call into Facebook's Graph API to retrieve those details?

Comment: Yes. I don't know if the token itself contains any information; I'd rather suspect it to be completely random and stored somewhere together with the user id and expiration time for lookup. But to get user details, you use the token and make an API request that reads those fields.

Comment: Gotcha. In that case this seems simple enough. Thanks!